# Read 2 images separately in 2 different variables

Tags: image

I have downloaded 2 images in one folder and I want to read them one by one in 2 different variables.

I am able to print 2 different files but not able to store these images in different variables. For eg. image 1 should be stored in var1 and 2nd in var2. Below is my code-

```
import os
path = r’C:\Users\Desktop\Projects\ImagePractise\Images’
for image in os.listdir(path):
cv2.imread(image)
print(image)
```